# How do I moq this IRepository?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, moq, xunit

I am trying to start with the basics but having trouble understanding how to create this moq object.

```
 public class TestRefMedicalSpecialty
{
    private Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>> mockRefMedicalRepo;

    public TestRefMedicalSpecialty()
    {
        var mockRefMedicalSpecialties = new List<RefMedicalSpecialty>
        {
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10000", Description = "Medical Specialty1"},
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10001", Description = "Medical Specialty2"},
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10002", Description = "Medical Specialty3"}
        };

        mockRefMedicalRepo = new Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>>();

        mockRefMedicalRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetAll()).Returns(mockRefMedicalSpecialties);

       // this.mockRefMedicalRepo = new Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>>().Object;
        this.mockRefMedicalRepo = mockRefMedicalRepo.Object;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetAll_Returns_Data()
    {

    }
}
```

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type '`Aamc.Ret.Data.IRepository<Aamc.Ret.Data.Models.RefMedicalSpecialty>`' to '`Moq.Mock<Aamc.Ret.Data.IRepository<Aamc.Ret.Data.Models.RefMedicalSpecialty>>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    Aamc.Ret.UnitTests

Comment: `Mock.Object` property returns a mock of the generic argument. so in your case `mockRefMedicalRepo.Object` is a `IRepository<Aamc.Ret.Data.Models.RefMedicalSpecialty>` but you are tryign to assign it to a `Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>>` as the error message states.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the Moq framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mock<T>.Object` property returns a mock of the generic argument `T`.

So in your case `mockRefMedicalRepo.Object` is a `IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>` but you are trying to assign it to a `Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>>` as the error message states.

Here is a possible alternative

```
public class TestRefMedicalSpecialty {
    private IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty> mockRefMedicalRepo;

    public TestRefMedicalSpecialty() {
        var mockRefMedicalSpecialties = new List<RefMedicalSpecialty>
        {
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10000", Description = "Medical Specialty1"},
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10001", Description = "Medical Specialty2"},
            new RefMedicalSpecialty {Code = "10002", Description = "Medical Specialty3"}
        };

        var mock = new Mock<IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty>>();

        mock.Setup(_ => _.GetAll()).Returns(mockRefMedicalSpecialties);

        this.mockRefMedicalRepo = mock.Object;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetAll_Returns_Data() {

        //pass the mocked repo into a dependent class and 
        //exercise test that relies on calling GetAll

    }
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the Moq framework